# Use a object as the src of a image tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html5 page that is dynamically updated based on the data item that is clicked on by the user. I have the url of the data item stored in a attribute named

```
mv-pic
```

However when I try and use this as the src of the image, all I get is a box outline and the image dosen't render. I can reproduce this error in this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MPzVu/10/). Simply click a list item and you will see what I mean.

Comment: It's setting the source of the image to 'mv-pic', the literal string. I can't see the code where you're actually setting the src, but I'd check that you didn't put mv-pic in quote marks.

Comment: where you are setting the text of `$('#mv-pic')`. First I think what you would want is to set the src and secondaly such a node doesn't exist in your fiddle setup.

Comment: Sorry the fiddle is a super rough copy of my code, zeroflagL provided a perfect answer though. Thankyou for looking. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#mv-pic').text(listItemclicked.picturePath);
```

It means "get the element with the id `mv-pic` and fill it with text. There is no element with the id `mv-pic`. You have an image whose `src` attribute is "mv-pic". Possible solution:

```
<img  height="100" width="100" id="mv-pic" />
...
$('#mv-pic').attr("src",listItemclicked.picturePath);
```